# How to Allow outgoing traffic to ports Mac Os

Tags: networking, macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

I am not a programmer and I have no experience with coding. Therefore, I want to ask about allowing outgoing traffic to ports on a Mac.

I want to open `TCP:80`, `TCP:11031` and `UDP:11235-11335` in Mac OS. What should I type in terminal for this purpose?

I have turned off the firewall, too. I gave up because I already tried everything I know - but ports are still blocked.

OS version: MacOs 10.8.5 Mountain Lion

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: mac OS 7, Mac OS 8, or Os X 10.8.5 ?  (They are very much not the same)

Comment: If port 80 outbound is blocked how does this Mac connect to the internet?

Comment: Relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117644/how-can-i-list-my-open-network-ports-with-netstat

Comment: How do you test if the ports are blocked? What services do you want to run on these ports?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access your computer from outside your local network make sure you have Port Forwarding correctly. Or maybe you can use UPnP rather.